# Metapost: vardef - draw a picture and return pairs

Tags: diagrams, metapost

In a `vardef`, I draw a `picture` and I want to return the `pairs` of the picture. Followed is small code. It can draw the picture - "I" shape but I don't know how to return the pairs - `p[]`.

If I uncomment the last one `draw origin -- p12;`, it said "xpart p12 undefined".

On the other hand, if I return `picture` from vardef and call it in main function, how can I get the `pairs` relating with the picture?

```
outputtemplate := "%j-%c.eps";
prologues := 1 ;

beginfig(1)
  vardef draw_I_shape (expr base, depth, width, tf ,tw) =
    save p;
    pair p[];

    p1 := base;
    p2 := p1 + (width, 0);
    p3 := p2 + (0, tf);
    p4 := p3 - ((width - tw) / 2, 0);
    p5 := p4 + (0, depth - 2 * tf);
    p6 := p5 + ((width - tw) / 2, 0);
    p7 := p6 + (0, tf);
    p8 := p7 - (width, 0);
    p9 := p8 - (0, tf);
    p10 := p9 + ((width - tw) / 2, 0);
    p11 := p10 - (0, depth - 2 * tf);
    p12 := p11 - ((width - tw) / 2, 0);

    picture shape;
    shape = image(
      draw p1--p2--p3--p4--p5--p6--p7--p8--p9--p10--p11--p12--cycle;
    );
    draw shape;
    p
  enddef;

  u = 0.1mm;
  pair p[];
  p = draw_I_shape (origin, 248u, 124u, 8u, 5u);
  % draw origin -- p12;

endfig;
```

Comment: It would be easier to create the path as a variable and return that, then you could you the `point x of y` notation to get the points in the path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do this differently.  I'd build a path to hold the points instead of trying to make an array.  And I'd write a `turtle` macro as I suggested in a comment to one of your earlier questions, something like this:

```
outputtemplate := "%j-%c.eps";
prologues := 3;

vardef turtle@# expr pr = 
    if known @#: 
        @# := @# -- point infinity of @# shifted pr
    else:
        @# := pr
    fi
enddef;

beginfig(1)
  vardef draw_I_shape (expr base, depth, width, tf ,tw) =
    save p;
    path p;
    turtle.p base ;
    turtle.p (width, 0);
    turtle.p (0, tf);
    turtle.p -(1/2(width-tw), 0);
    turtle.p (0, depth - 2 * tf);
    turtle.p ((width - tw) / 2, 0);
    turtle.p (0, tf);
    turtle.p -(width, 0);
    turtle.p -(0, tf);
    turtle.p ((width - tw) / 2, 0);
    turtle.p -(0, depth - 2 * tf);
    turtle.p -((width - tw) / 2, 0);
    p := p--cycle;
    draw p;
    p
  enddef;

  u = 0.1mm;
  path P;
  P = draw_I_shape (origin, 248u, 124u, 8u, 5u);

  draw origin -- point 6 of P withcolor red;
  draw P scaled 1/2 rotated -20 shifted (42, 32) withcolor blue;

endfig;
end
```

which produces:

[image]

Notes:

- The suffix `@#` notation on the `vardef` allows you to pass a suffix.  This is how all the `boxit` etc macros work in `boxes.mp`.
- So as defined, you need to call `turtle` with the name of a `path` variable as the suffix, and a `pair` expression as the argument.
- Inside the definition, `@#` works like any other variable so you can use it in normal expressions.
- `if known @#` returns `true` if the path has been defined already, and false otherwise
- So if you call `turtle` with a new (empty) path, `if known @#` will be false and the macro will simply assign the pair to the path
- When you call it again, the path is not empty so `if known @#` will be true, and now the macro expands to `@# := @# -- point infinity of @# shifted pr` which redefines the path `@#` to be itself plus a straight line to the end point shifted by the argument.  This is slightly backwards way of expressing it I suppose, but the net effect is to add the argument relative to the end of the path.
- `point infinity of p` is a convenient way to refer to the point at the end of path `p`.
- You could enhance the `turtle` macro to check that the suffix is a path and that the argument is a `pair`.

### More than one step at a time

You can take this idea one step further my wrapping the "turtle" part up in a loop, so that you can specify all the points in one go:

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";
vardef creep@#(text t) = 
    for $=t:
        @# := if known @#: @# -- point infinity of @# shifted fi $;
    endfor
enddef;

vardef get_I_path(expr dp, wd, tf, tw) = 
    save p, h, v;
    numeric h, v; h = 1/2(wd-tw); v = dp-2tf;
    path p; 
    creep.p(
        wd * right, tf * up, h * left, v * up, h * right, tf * up, 
        wd * left, tf * down, h * right, v * down, h * left, tf * down,
    );
    p := p--cycle;
    p
enddef;

beginfig(1);

    numeric u; 
    u = 0.1mm;

    path S;
    S = get_I_path(248u, 124u, 8u, 5u);

    draw S;
    draw point 0 of S -- point 6 of S withcolor red;
    draw S scaled 1/2 rotated -20 shifted (42, 42) withcolor blue;
endfig;
end.
```

The feature of MP syntax I'm using here is the `text` type parameter to the macro.  This lets you give an arbitrary list of expressions or suffixes separated by commas.  Again there are some good examples of this in the `boxes.mp` source file provided with MP.

```
vardef creep@#(text t) = 
    for $=t:
        @# := if known @#: @# -- point infinity of @# shifted fi $;
    endfor
enddef;
```

Here when `creep` is expanded the whole of the comma separated argument is read into `t` and then the loop `for $=t` splits it up by comma and puts each term in the argument into the loop variable `$`.

The body of the loop then adds `$` to the of the path `@#` as before, (except that I've used a more compressed version of the `if` construction).

This version produces this:

[image]

You'll notice that I've managed to move point 0 of the path along one place.  If this was a problem you could start the path with `origin`.

As a matter of style, I've take the `draw` command out of the first level macro.  I find it easier write macros that just do one logical thing, that is create the path, rather than create the path and draw it as a side effect.

I've also used the `right`, `left`, `up`, `down` macros because they make the code easier to read (in English!).  I could have written `(wd,0)` instead of `wd * right`, etc.

Comment: @ Thruston: Awesome. Due to my knowledge, I don't understand `@#` and the macro `turtle`. Can turtle work on `picture`? For those that can't draw in `one stroke`, `path` won't work.

Comment: As I've defined `turtle`, you need to pass the name of a `path` variable as a suffix, and  single `pair` expression as the argument.  I'll add some more explanation in the answer

Comment: @ Thruston: how can I rotate the shape in the macro `draw_I_shape`? All the points defined in the `path p` are the key points and will be referred by other points. `p := p--cycle rotated -45;` doesn't work. `draw p rotated -45;` in macro will rotate the shape, but the `path p` won't rotate in main function.

Comment: Extended discussion is discouraged in comments!  You need to give a hint to MP because path joins like `--` have a lower precedence than transformations like `rotated`, so try: :  `p := (p--cycle) rotated -45;`

Comment: Thank you! ! @Thruston I would pay attention to the rule.